# PHP retrieve data from mysql table and display as it is

Tags: php, mysql

my mysql table has a field call address that field display address like this

```
103
Melbourne
Australia
```

but when i retrieve this from the table it display like

```
103 Melbourne Australia
```

when I use this code

```
<?php foreach($alldata as $data){ echo $data->address; } ?>
```

how to display this as it is on table?

Comment: <?php foreach($alldata as $data){ echo $data->address; } ?>

Comment: use `nl2br($address);`

Comment: Line breaks are ignored in HTML.

Comment: @user3099298, you should not add code to the comments, but rather edit your question. There is an __edit__ link in the botton of it that you can use to add the php code you are using. Comments are not a good place for adding information to the question, as they are not catching the attention of the users.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [**`nl2br()`**](http://www.php.net/function.nl2br)

```
<?php foreach($alldata as $data){ echo nl2br($data->address); } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks are ignored in HTML, so you need to use `nl2br()` which will add `<br>` for new line.

```
<?php foreach($alldata as $data){ echo nl2br($data->address); } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
```

//table query ....
$address //assuming it is your variable...

echo nl2br($address);?>